# Intersection of a variety with an open

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a variety and $U$ an open of $V$.
Is the following statement true? If $V \cap U$ is irreducible, then $V$ is irreducible.

Comment: You really ask if a variety is irreducible when it contains a irreducible open subset? Have you thought about it a few seconds before asking here?